# How to show that $\forall n \geq 1$, $\frac{n^{2n}}{n!^2} \geq (\frac{n+1}{n})^{n^2-n}$?

Tags: asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I tried using the fact that $(n+1)/n \leq 2$ and thus $\frac{n^{2n}}{n!^2} \geq 2^{n^2-n}$ but this does not seem to be true.

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$?

Comment: Initially I had thought about it. But seeing how n is everywhere in the inequality I decided not to use induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can proceed by induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ is easy to check. Suppose that the inequality holds for $1,2,\ldots,n$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{{(n + 1)^{2n + 2} }}{{(n + 1)!^2 }} = \frac{{(n + 1)^{2n} }}{{n!^2 }} &= \frac{{n^{2n} }}{{n!^2 }}\left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}} \right)^{2n}  \ge \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}} \right)^{n^2  - n} \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}} \right)^{2n} \\& = \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}} \right)^{(n + 1)^2  - (n + 1)}  \ge \left( {\frac{{n + 2}}{{n + 1}}} \right)^{(n + 1)^2  - (n + 1)} ,
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.